# What is the Jenkins' slave memory footprint?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am aware of https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Consideration+for+Large+Scale+Jenkins+Deployment which talks about Large scale deployment and I plan to use Jenkins slaves to run performance benchmarking jobs on machines. But I was wondering how much impact will running the Jenkins Slave have on these machines have on the performance numbers, since the process for which the performance benchmark is to be done is highly CPU intensive. Is it a bad idea to use Jenkins to manage the runs? Should I keep doing these things manually, instead?